# Symfony2 in own directory and using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, symfony, apache2

I have Symfony2 installed in `<host>/Symfony/` though with the default `.htaccess` in `/var/www/Symfony/web/` when I go to:

```
<host>/Symfony/web/app.php/hello/James
```

I get redirected to:

```
<host>/hello/James
```

I want to get redirected to:

```
<host>/Symfony/hello/James
```

I think it is something to do with this in the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
```

I not very good with `mod_rewrite`

**EDIT**

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# startpage (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewritting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the startpage because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # The following rewrites all other queries to the front controller. The
    # condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual
    # hosting, the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of the
    # app.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments as well, providing
    # a safe, one-size fits all solution.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app_dev.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: or you could just put the app.php in a subdirectory(and use RewriteBase /Symfony ) or prefix your urls in your route config instead of messing with apache conf.

Comment: I really want to do this in `.htaccess`

Comment: I have seen [2.2.5 and 2.3](https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/3820302) Symphony .htaccess files and they don't have that piece of code, which I guess is trying to determine the whole path to `app,php`. But, as you know it, try replacing those 3 lines with `RewriteRule .? /Symfony/web/app.php [L]`

Comment: lines `35-37` in `web/.htaccess` I've got. I have updated my answer with `.htaccess` contents. (I can see you point, there are not in the github version)

Comment: again ,just use RewriteBase in htaccess , that's what i told you.